# Moq: how to call method predicate inside linq to mocks query?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, moq

There have been few similar questions on the topic on stack overflow, but I found nothing related to Moq as such.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to wrap the 'where' part of the following query:

```
MyObject o = (from mock in Mocks.Of<MyObject>() 
              where mock.Property == 1 
              select mock).First();
```

So that I can pass lambda with only the criteria (i.e. the mock.Property == 1 part). My first (and failed, obviously) attempt was the following:

```
public static T GetMockOf<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
{
    T obj = (from mock in Mocks.Of<T>() 
             where predicate(mock)
             select mock).First();
    return obj;
}
// ...

MyObject o = GetMockOf<MyObject>( mock => mock.Property == 1 );
```

This is failing because the predicate is called on infinite number of mocks - inifinite number of times - and the code hangs. I tried switching to predicate.Invoke() instead of predicate(), but this ends up with NotSupportedException.

While searching through Stack Overflow, I noticed that people suggested using Expressions, LinqKit or Dynamic Linq for similar tasks, however, it's very difficult for a Linq rookie like me to dig into these topics deep enough.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible with Moq? If so, what's the easiest way to achieve it? Not sure if it changes anything, but I'm using mono for my coding, not original .NET.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish period... are you writing unit tests? ... what functionality are you testing?... the second code sample has a class, but the first is just a query... etc :)

Comment: Here's the deal: in linq to mocks I like the ability to setup mock in more declarative way (e.g. mock.Method() == value). However, I displike the rest of the linq syntax (where, first etc.), So I'd like to wrap the linq query in a method and just pass into it a lambda with the declarative part I like, to be able to use in my unit tests something like: MyObject o = GetMockOf<MyObject>( mock => mock.Property == 1 );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already supported by Moq v4.

```
MyObject o = Mock.Of<MyObject>(mock => mock.Property == 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm quite ashamed for not looking through the documentation deep enough. Next time I will do better!

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation for the functional specifications syntax is scattered. See my [blog entry](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2011/04/20/moq_v4_functional_specifications) for a summary and some links.